# Does updating application pool advanced settings incur an automatic application pool recycle?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-state, application-pool

I just updated the `Application Pool > Advanced Settings` in IIS. I set `Recycling.Regular Time Interval = 0` and clicked OK.

After doing so I noticed `Application Pool.Applications = 0`. Previous to updating the advanced setting, `Applications = 4`. I then received error reports from end-users that corresponded to Session Timeout errors shown in the Application Event Log (in Windows Event Log)

I did not click the Recycle button after updating the Pool setting.

This suggests that updating these settings incurs an automatic recycling of the pool. Is this actually the case?

Are there similar settings that when updated in Sites cause an automatic site restart?

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting called disallowRotationOnConfigChange which controls that, whose default value is false unfortunately ,

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling

Whether a setting restarts the site or application is really hard to tell generally, as the documentation might be confusing. Thus, you should always test that out on another spare machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if updating `disallowRotationOnConfigChange` also recycles the pool when it's changed to True?